# Powerpoint: remote pointing and slide track device

Tags: presentation

I think that this question may not be suitable for this forum. But I need your help. I am planning to buy a remote pointing (not only just pointing, we will be able to track the slides) device for my powerpoint presentations. I always use Ubuntu and powerpoint with libreoffice impress. I have been looking products on amazon, most of them are either for Windows or MAC. I am not sure whether they will work on Ubuntu. I think that at least some of of you have been using a device for presentations on Ubuntu. It would be great if you share one that will work seamlessly with Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Powerpoint is an application in the Microsoft Office Suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience most of the time when you connect a remote via usb bluetooth adapter in ubuntu 10.04 and up, they will behave basically like a mouse. So you will have access to the basic functions e.g. left-click, right-click and so on. 
But some of the special functions or buttons advertised for the product will most likely not work.
So I wouldn't go for anything too fancy.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Can you share me the product that you bought.

Comment: I used the Logitech R400 Presenter a lot...I think it was ubuntu 10.10 back then...didn't need to do presentations in a while but I'm sure it'll work with the ubuntu 11.xx versions as well.

Comment: a smaller alternative would be this one: http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=16448